# How to bind yaml list to a java list in springboot?

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, yaml, bind

I have a list in my yml file which i need to bind in my java springboot application, how do i go about it ?

`fruits:
- Apple
- Bannana`

Ideally i want something like

`@Value("${filters.siteID}")
 List siteIDs;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation has an example in ["24.6.1 Loading YAML"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml)

Define your list like

```
my:
    fruits:
        - Apple
        - Bannana
```

And create a config properties class to represent it:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class FruitConfig {
    private final List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> getFruits() {
        return this.fruits;
    }
}
```

Then use this class in your code in places that need the config

```
@Autowired
FruitConfig fruitConfig;

...  {
    System.out.println(fruitConfig.getFruits());
}
```

direct binding to `@Value` doesn't seem to work because of the way `@Value` works

Answer (score 5):

There is also another opportunity if you want to avoid to create a property class and keep using `@Value` and if your list is not very long.

Define your list like

```
my:
  fruits: Apple,Banana
```

And use it, e.g.

with Kotlin

```
@Value("#{'\${my.fruits:}'.split(',')}")
private lateinit var fruits: List<String>
```

or Java

```
@Value("#{'${my.fruits:}'.split(',')}")
private final List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note: the colon after `fruits` is optional to avoid startup errors if you use multiple profiles and this property does not exist in all.